# Is there a number code to capture F1 key press - 112 doesn't work

Tags: windows-7, lazarus

I'm using the KeyPress event on a text entry field in Lazarus on Windows7 to detect and interpret certain key sequences but I want to detect F1 to pop up a Help dialog.

I can capture #13 as the Return key no problem, but using #112 does not seem to catch F1.

My code is as follows:

```
procedure TForm1.keyCatcherKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: char);
  begin
    if ( AnsiContainsStr('0123456789',Key) ) then
      begin
        {my processing code}
      end
    else
      if ( Key = #13 ) then
        begin
          {my processing code}
    ... some other key checks that all work fine...
    else
      if ( Key = #112) then
        showHelp();
```

Is F1 catchable this way and is this the right code to look for?

Comment: Use the `OnKeyDown` event and test for `VK_F1` key code. The same applies to enter key handler (in your code the `#13` branch) which you should move there and test for `VK_RETURN` key code.

Comment: Getting 'Identifier  not found "VK_F1". Do I need an extra uses include?

Comment: They should be in lcltype unit.

Comment: Got it... thanks for the pointers... There's an explanation here: http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=14814.0 Any chance you could explain why Function keys need to be captured this way but Return seems to work both ways?

Comment: Briefly, the `OnKeyPress` event is fired only when the key press produces a char. And F1 key doesn't produce a char, whilst enter does (a new line feed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks To TLama's guidance above I found the following post on the Lazarus forum which got me a solution:

http://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=14814.0

My code for key press detection is now split between normal characters being detected with the `KeyPress` event and 'special' keypresses being detected with the `OnKeyDown` event.

```
procedure TForm1.keyCatcherKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: char);
  begin
    if ( AnsiContainsStr('0123456789',Key) ) then
      begin
        {my processing code}
      end
    else
    ... some other key checks that all work fine...;
```

and

```
      if ( Key = VK_Return ) then
        begin
          {my processing code}
      else
        if ( Key = VK_F1 ) then
          showHelp();
```